# Actor (Akka) not receiving messages after DB connection

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka

I have a very simple database writer actor just for writing some entries to Mongo with Casbah, but it refuses (no errors) to receive any messages after the connection to DB. If i'm remove `client` and `db` vals from the actor, it receives messages. I've also tried to encapsulate connection to some object, but it still doesn't work after the connection to DB.

```
class DBWriter extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val client = MongoClient(host, port)
  val db     = client(dbName)

  def receive = {
    case Write(collection, entry) => db(collection).save(entry)
  }
}

class StatisticsActor extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  val writer = context.actorOf(Props[DBWriter], "dbWriterActor")
  def receive = {
    case mes: SM => writer ! Write(....)
    case NoConnection => writer ! Write(....)
    case NCTime(time) => writer ! Write(....)
    ....
  }
  ....
}
```

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Can we see more code - where you create the actor and send it a message? Have you enabled all the logging of akka (see the chapter in the manual for this)?

Comment: Yes, I think that the connection don't work to your MongoDB..

Comment: @EmilIvanov Added some code, yes i've tried to find the reason in logs, but there is nothing interesting, if i place some log messages in construction, there are will be printed, but not the ones that in the DBWriters receive method

Comment: @twillouer Connection is ok, cause other parts (not actors) works fine =)

Comment: important part : is "collection" and "entry" immutable ? or, at least, never modify by another part ? You can add more logs to see where he is blocked. Like "log.info("connection ok") just after "client(dbName)", and log.info("receive Write {}, {}", collection, entry) before and after db(collection).save(entry).

Comment: @twillouer yes collection just a String name of mongo collection, and entry is MongoDBObject. The problem is that actor doesn't receives/reacts on messages

Comment: for me, it's like the actor is dead (doen't connect and stop). can you add more logs ?

Comment: Just a guess, but using a thread pool executor for the event dispatcher might do the trick. See [the Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0/scala/dispatchers.html).

Comment: @twillouer actually you was close, actor just didn't have enough time to respond to messages, all test were passed to the moment actor was ready to do something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. It was pretty simple, problem was with thread, actors just didn't have enough time to connect to mongo and write to it, all test were passed to that moment.

Comment: Note that MongoClient instance actually represents a pool of connections to the database. If you use the same database from other places (other actors) you should share the same MongoClient instance.